# how do you find and save duplicated rows in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, rows

I have an array e.g.

```
Array = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
```

And i would like something that would output the following:

```
Repeated = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
```

Preserving the number of repeated rows would work too, e.g.

```
Repeated = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

I thought the solution might include numpy.unique, but i can't get it to work, is there a native python / numpy function?

Comment: But unique is used to obtain the *unique* numbers, not the duplicate ones. Is this always a list of list of integers? Or can the objects be arbitrary objects?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 22):

Using the new `axis` functionality of [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) alongwith `return_counts=True` that gives us the unique rows and the corresponding counts for each of those rows, we can mask out the rows with `counts > 1` and thus have our desired output, like so -

```
In [688]: a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])

In [689]: unq, count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)

In [690]: unq[count>1]
Out[690]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the indexes of repeated rows? For example, `[0, 5]` and `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to get indices of the repeated rows

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
unq, count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_counts=True)
repeated_groups = unq[count > 1]

for repeated_group in repeated_groups:
    repeated_idx = np.argwhere(np.all(a == repeated_group, axis=1))
    print(repeated_idx.ravel())

# [0 5]
# [1 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `Repeated = list(set(map(tuple, Array)))` if you didn't necessarily need order preserved. The advantage of this is you don't need additional dependencies like numpy. Depending on what you're doing next, you could probably get away with `Repeated = set(map(tuple, Array))` and avoid a type conversion if you would like.