# How to get indices of tensors of same value in a 2-d tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, indices

As described in title, given a 2-d tensor, let's say:

```
tensor([
    [0, 1, 0, 1], # A
    [1, 1, 0, 1], # B
    [1, 0, 0, 1], # C
    [0, 1, 0, 1], # D
    [1, 1, 0, 1], # E
    [1, 1, 0, 1]  # F
])
```

That's easy enough to tell that "A and D", "B, E and F" are two groups of tensors,

that are of same value(that means A == D and B == E == F).

So my question is:

> How to get indices of those groups?

Details:

> Input: tensor above
>
> Output: (0, 3), (1, 4, 5)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you find and save duplicated rows in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099479/how-do-you-find-and-save-duplicated-rows-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using PyTorch functions:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([
    [0, 1, 0, 1], # A
    [1, 1, 0, 1], # B
    [1, 0, 0, 1], # C
    [0, 1, 0, 1], # D
    [1, 1, 0, 1], # E
    [1, 1, 0, 1]  # F
])

_, inv, counts = torch.unique(x, dim=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
print([tuple(torch.where(inv == i)[0].tolist()) for i, c, in enumerate(counts) if counts[i] > 1])
# > [(0, 3), (1, 4, 5)]
```